# Remove minimal number of elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization

Given the numbers $ 1,2,..,2n + 1 $ , $ n > 0$ , remove as few numbers as possible so that among the remaining numbers no number is equal to the sum of two other numbers.

After removal of first $n$ numbers , remaining numbers satisfy the required property.
I am convinced that at least $n$ numbers should be removed so it is not possible to do better but I can't prove it.

Comment: Search the web for sum free subsets.

Answer (score 1):

It is surely sufficient to remove $n$ numbers: we can remove all $n$ even numbers. Then all numbers that are left are odd, so the sum of any two of them is even and in particular not one of the numbers left.

To show that we need to remove at least $n$ numbers, consider the largest number $M$ that remains. We distinguish two cases:

- $M = 2\ell+1$ is odd. We have removed all $2(n-\ell)$ numbers larger than $M$, and we also have to remove one number out of each of the $\ell$ pairs $(1,2\ell)$, $(2,2\ell-1)$, ... $(\ell,\ell+1)$. So we remove at least $2(n-\ell) + \ell= 2n-\ell \geq n$ numbers (as $\ell \leq n$).
- $M = 2\ell$ is even. Now there are $2(n-\ell)+1$ numbers larger than $M$ and we can form $\ell-1$ pairs: $(1,2\ell-1)$ until $(\ell-1,\ell+1)$. So again we remove at least $2(n-\ell) + (\ell-1) = 2n - \ell \geq n$ numbers.

In each case, we see that at least $n$ numbers need to be removed.